# How to download videos that have subtitles using youtube-dl "yt-dlp"?

Tags: audio, video, youtube, youtube-dl

I have the following command which tries to download videos that only have subtitles and ignore everything else. However, this command doesn't filter it out and downloads them anyway.

Any idea why?

```
yt-dlp https://www.youtube.com/c/UpgradedYouPodcastLakatosPéter/videos --match-filter subtitles --min-sleep-interval 4 --max-sleep-interval 6 --audio-multistreams --write-auto-subs --extract-audio --audio-format wav -o "%(title)s.%(ext)s" --restrict-filenames --sub-langs hu-hu,-live_chat
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use

```
--match-filter requested_subtitles
```